# Rails SQL Query with find

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, find

I want this SQL query to be written in rails controller using find:

```
select id,name from questions
where id not in (select question_id from levels_questions where level_id=15)
```

How will I do this? I am using Rails framework and MySQL.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Simple way:

```
ids = LevelsQuestion.all(:select => "question_id", 
        :conditions => "level_id = 15").collect(&:question_id)
Question.all(:select => "id, name", :conditions => ["id not in (?)", ids])
```

One shot:

```
Question.all(:select => "id, name",
:conditions => ["id not in (select question_id from levels_questions where level_id=15)"])
```

Comment: can this be given in the options_from_collection_for_select in the select_tag?

Comment: I just edited it to change it from find to all. Select the version you like. I guess something made you change your mind. I like the other solution as well. Let us know why you selected my answer over the other one.

Answer (score 28):

```
Question.find_all_by_sql('select id,name from questions where id not in (select question_id from levels_questions where level_id=15)')
```

This is admittedly non-ActiveRecord-ish, but I find that complicated queries such as this tend to be LESS clear/efficient when using the AR macros.  If you already have the SQL constructed, you might as well use it.

Some suggestions: encapsulate this find call in a method INSIDE the Question class to hide the details from the controller/view, and consider other SQL constructions that may be more efficient (eg, an OUTER JOIN where levels_questions.question_id is null)

Comment: cool...  first my answer was selected, then I find I have a -1 and I've been DEselected.  and now the author of the selected answer says mine is better..?  heh, ouch :-}

Comment: well. I said yours was better when I saw it the first time, not after. I think your one-liner is superior. I gave you a +1 for your answer. I think you need to modify your answer to replace model.find_by_sql with Question.find_all_by_sql, then it will serve the author's purpose.

Comment: thanks, ryan. I'm not bitter, it's just my REPUTATION at stake...  :-D

Answer (score 3):

And the rails 3 way:

```
ids = LevelsQuestion.select(:question_id).where(:level_id => 15).collect(&:question_id)
Question.select(:id, :name).where("id not in (?)", ids)
```