# query on two groups ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two values @details and @users as below

```
@details = ProjectTeamDetail.find_all_by_project_id_and_stage_id($projectID, stage.stage_id)
@users = User.find(:all)
```

ProjectTeamDetail Model has user_id column

My requirement is to get the users from user table which are not in @details. Hope you understand my requirement.

Comment: i think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985211/rails-sql-query-with-find) link will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails 3 way:

```
@details = ProjectTeamDetail.where(project_id: $projectID, stage_id: stage.stage_id)
@users = User.all.where("id NOT IN (?)", @details.map(&:id))
```

Comment: Also, I'd be sort of wary of using global variables, especially here. It seems almost certainly unnecessary...