# Consultation with subquery rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, search, subquery

select * From Incomes where customer_id in (select id From Customers where name like  "j%")

how do I make an inquiry on the rails?
I want to make a customer survey!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not in english. A spanish version of stackoverflow is on the way. But http://stackoverflow.com/ is for programming questions in english please.

Comment: @max it is not spanish

Comment: Sorry portugese. Which makes it even more off topic. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: edit your question and re-write it all in english if you want help. StackOverflow it's in english.

Second, to make a SQL query in Rails, you can search in SO. I found this that can solve your question

[Rails 3 execute custom sql query without a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408285/rails-3-execute-custom-sql-query-without-a-model)

or

[Rails SQL Query with find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985211/rails-sql-query-with-find)

Good luck.

Comment: this worked for me  Income.where(:customer_id => Customer.searchId(params[:search])).order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(12) and in the model where("name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%") thanks for help me

Comment: You're welcome.

If you're question is solved, mark the answer with the solution as the solution to close the thread.